# Getting a class's filepath starting from the current working directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, filepath

I am trying to print the path to a file. I want the full path from the current working directory to the file.

I am using the `inspect` module to find the path to my file. However this will give me the full path which is not what I'm looking for.

```
import inspect

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print(inspect.getfile(self.__class__))
```

Now for the filename itself I can use `os.path.basename`. But this will give me just the filename which is also not what I want.

```
import inspect
import os

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        path = inspect.getfile(self.__class__)
        filename = os.path.basename(path)
        print(path)
        print(filename)
```

It would be relatively easy to use the `path` in combination with `os.getcwd()` to get the path I am looking for. This will give me the result I am looking for.

```
import inspect
import os


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        path = inspect.getfile(self.__class__)
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        print(path[len(cwd):])
```

I am wondering if there is a better/easier way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe No I didn't. This is indeed better, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [os.path.relpath()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) does what you want it to.

Example:

```
import os, inspect

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = os.path.relpath(inspect.getfile(self.__class__))


foo = Foo()
print(foo.path)
```